# Message content is too long, length must be less or equal to 2000

Tags: c#, discord.net

whenever i do !fortnite pc Ninja it works just fine but if i did !fortnite pc geo.java it would give me that error. i have tried quite a bit of ways to fix this and none of them have worked. I even tried other names and they worked. I think it is the "." in the name but i dont know how i would fix this.. any help would be nice thanks.
here is the code:

```
[Command("fortnite")]
    public async Task fortnite(string type, [Remainder]string name)
    {
        using (var client = new FortniteClient("aec756fb-d0ac-4808-a1e1-9be7c421ebcc"))
        {
            try
            {
                if (type == "pc" || type == "Pc")
                {
                    var response = await client.FindPlayerAsync(Platform.Pc, Convert.ToString(name));
                    //solo
                    var solokills = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.Kills].ValueInt;
                    var soloscore = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.Score].ValueInt;
                    var solospm = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.ScorePerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var solokd = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.KillDeathRatio].ValueDec;
                    var solomatches = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.Matches].ValueInt;
                    var solowr = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.WinRatio].ValueDec;
                    var solokpm = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.KillsPerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var solotrnrating = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.TrnRating].Value;

                    var pcsolo = Helpers.CreateEmbed(Context, "**Solo**\n\nScore: " + soloscore + "\nScore Per Match: " + solospm + "\nK/D: " + solokd + "\nW/R: " + solowr + "\nMatches: " + solomatches + "\nKills: " + solokills + "\nKills Per Match: " + solokpm + "\nTRN Rating: " + solotrnrating);
                    pcsolo.WithThumbnailUrl("https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/fortnite.png");
                    await Helpers.SendMessage(Context, pcsolo);
                    //duo
                    //    await ReplyAsync("", false, pcsolo);

                    var duokills = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.Kills].ValueInt;
                    var duoscore = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.Score].ValueInt;
                    var duospm = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.ScorePerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var duokd = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.KillDeathRatio].ValueDec;
                    var duomatches = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.Matches].ValueInt;
                    var duowr = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.WinRatio].ValueDec;
                    var duokpm = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.KillsPerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var duotrnrating = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.TrnRating].Value;

                    var pcduo = Helpers.CreateEmbed(Context, "**Duo**\n\nScore: " + duoscore + "\nScore Per Match: " + duospm + "\nK/D: " + duokd + "\nW/R: " + duowr + "\nMatches: " + duomatches + "\nKills: " + duokills + "\nKills Per Match: " + duokpm + "\nTRN Rating: " + duotrnrating);
                    pcduo.WithThumbnailUrl("https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/fortnite.png");
                    await Helpers.SendMessage(Context, pcduo);
                    //squad
                    var Squadkills = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.Kills].ValueInt;
                    var Squadscore = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.Score].ValueInt;
                    var Squadspm = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.ScorePerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var Squadkd = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.KillDeathRatio].ValueDec;
                    var Squadmatches = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.Matches].ValueInt;
                    var Squadwr = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.WinRatio].ValueDec;
                    var Squadkpm = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.KillsPerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var Squadtrnrating = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.TrnRating].Value;

                    var pcSquad = Helpers.CreateEmbed(Context, "**Squad**\n\nScore: " + Squadscore + "\nScore Per Match: " + Squadspm + "\nK/D: " + Squadkd + "\nW/R: " + Squadwr + "\nMatches: " + Squadmatches + "\nKills: " + Squadkills + "\nKills Per Match: " + Squadkpm + "\nTRN Rating: " + Squadtrnrating);
                    pcSquad.WithThumbnailUrl("https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/fortnite.png");
                    await Helpers.SendMessage(Context, pcSquad);
                    // await ReplyAsync("", false, pcSquad);
                }
                else if (type == "psn" || type == "Psn")
                {
                    var response = await client.FindPlayerAsync(Platform.Psn, name);
                    //solo
                    var solokills = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.Kills].ValueInt;
                    var soloscore = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.Score].ValueInt;
                    var solospm = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.ScorePerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var solokd = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.KillDeathRatio].ValueDec;
                    var solomatches = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.Matches].ValueInt;
                    var solowr = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.WinRatio].ValueDec;
                    var solokpm = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.KillsPerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var solotrnrating = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.TrnRating].Value;

                    var psnsolo = Helpers.CreateEmbed(Context, "**Solo**\n\nScore: " + soloscore + "\nScore Per Match: " + solospm + "\nK/D: " + solokd + "\nW/R: " + solowr + "\nMatches: " + solomatches + "\nKills: " + solokills + "\nKills Per Match: " + solokpm + "\nTRN Rating: " + solotrnrating);
                    psnsolo.WithThumbnailUrl("https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/fortnite.png");
                    await Helpers.SendMessage(Context, psnsolo);
                    //duo

                    var duokills = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.Kills].ValueInt;
                    var duoscore = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.Score].ValueInt;
                    var duospm = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.ScorePerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var duokd = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.KillDeathRatio].ValueDec;
                    var duomatches = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.Matches].ValueInt;
                    var duowr = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.WinRatio].ValueDec;
                    var duokpm = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.KillsPerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var duotrnrating = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.TrnRating].Value;

                    var psnduo = Helpers.CreateEmbed(Context, "**Duo**\n\nScore: " + duoscore + "\nScore Per Match: " + duospm + "\nK/D: " + duokd + "\nW/R: " + duowr + "\nMatches: " + duomatches + "\nKills: " + duokills + "\nKills Per Match: " + duokpm + "\nTRN Rating: " + duotrnrating);
                    psnduo.WithThumbnailUrl("https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/fortnite.png");
                    await Helpers.SendMessage(Context, psnduo);
                    //squad
                    var Squadkills = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.Kills].ValueInt;
                    var Squadscore = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.Score].ValueInt;
                    var Squadspm = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.ScorePerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var Squadkd = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.KillDeathRatio].ValueDec;
                    var Squadmatches = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.Matches].ValueInt;
                    var Squadwr = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.WinRatio].ValueDec;
                    var Squadkpm = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.KillsPerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var Squadtrnrating = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.TrnRating].Value;

                    var psnSquad = Helpers.CreateEmbed(Context, "**Squad**\n\nScore: " + Squadscore + "\nScore Per Match: " + Squadspm + "\nK/D: " + Squadkd + "\nW/R: " + Squadwr + "\nMatches: " + Squadmatches + "\nKills: " + Squadkills + "\nKills Per Match: " + Squadkpm + "\nTRN Rating: " + Squadtrnrating);
                    psnSquad.WithThumbnailUrl("https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/fortnite.png");
                    await Helpers.SendMessage(Context, psnSquad);

                }
                else if (type == "xbl" || type == "Xbl")
                {
                    var response = await client.FindPlayerAsync(Platform.Xbl, name);
                    //solo
                    var solokills = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.Kills].ValueInt;
                    var soloscore = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.Score].ValueInt;
                    var solospm = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.ScorePerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var solokd = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.KillDeathRatio].ValueDec;
                    var solomatches = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.Matches].ValueInt;
                    var solowr = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.WinRatio].ValueDec;
                    var solokpm = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.KillsPerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var solotrnrating = response.Stats[Playlist.Solo][Stat.TrnRating].Value;

                    var xblsolo = Helpers.CreateEmbed(Context, "**Solo**\n\nScore: " + soloscore + "\nScore Per Match: " + solospm + "\nK/D: " + solokd + "\nW/R: " + solowr + "\nMatches: " + solomatches + "\nKills: " + solokills + "\nKills Per Match: " + solokpm + "\nTRN Rating: " + solotrnrating);
                    xblsolo.WithThumbnailUrl("https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/fortnite.png");
                    await Helpers.SendMessage(Context, xblsolo);
                    //duo
                    var duokills = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.Kills].ValueInt;
                    var duoscore = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.Score].ValueInt;
                    var duospm = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.ScorePerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var duokd = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.KillDeathRatio].ValueDec;
                    var duomatches = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.Matches].ValueInt;
                    var duowr = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.WinRatio].ValueDec;
                    var duokpm = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.KillsPerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var duotrnrating = response.Stats[Playlist.Duo][Stat.TrnRating].Value;

                    var xblduo = Helpers.CreateEmbed(Context, "**Duo**\n\nScore: " + duoscore + "\nScore Per Match: " + duospm + "\nK/D: " + duokd + "\nW/R: " + duowr + "\nMatches: " + duomatches + "\nKills: " + duokills + "\nKills Per Match: " + duokpm + "\nTRN Rating: " + duotrnrating);
                    xblduo.WithThumbnailUrl("https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/fortnite.png");
                    await Helpers.SendMessage(Context, xblduo);
                    //squad
                    var Squadkills = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.Kills].ValueInt;
                    var Squadscore = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.Score].ValueInt;
                    var Squadspm = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.ScorePerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var Squadkd = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.KillDeathRatio].ValueDec;
                    var Squadmatches = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.Matches].ValueInt;
                    var Squadwr = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.WinRatio].ValueDec;
                    var Squadkpm = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.KillsPerMatch].ValueDec;
                    var Squadtrnrating = response.Stats[Playlist.Squad][Stat.TrnRating].Value;

                    var xblSquad = Helpers.CreateEmbed(Context, "**Squad**\n\nScore: " + Squadscore + "\nScore Per Match: " + Squadspm + "\nK/D: " + Squadkd + "\nW/R: " + Squadwr + "\nMatches: " + Squadmatches + "\nKills: " + Squadkills + "\nKills Per Match: " + Squadkpm + "\nTRN Rating: " + Squadtrnrating);

                    xblSquad.WithThumbnailUrl("https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/fortnite.png");
                    await Helpers.SendMessage(Context, xblSquad);
                }
                else
                {
                    //error message
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                await ReplyAsync(ex.ToString());
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not digging into API-specific issues but, if your message is too long then split it and send multiple messages.

You seem to have 3 parts in your message : `solo`, `duo` and `squad`, send one message for each.

If that isn't enough then grab chunks of your final message `string`, preferably splitting at punctuation/spaces and/or add ellipsis so that your message looks nice to the users reading them.

Answer (score 0):

Messy code aside, you are trying to send a message with too many characters in one of your fields in one of your embeds.
From the code you provided, we can't see which field is too long.

In your case, I would edit your `Helpers` class to automatically split a message into multiple fields if the message is over 2000 characters. Hope this helps in any way.